# Assign role to user in Apex

Tags: apex, user-record, roles

I'm trying to assign a role to a user using Apex. Here my code:

```
user.UserRole=[select UserRoleId from UserRole where Name='CEO'].UserRoleId;
```

But the debugger give the error:

> illegal assignment fro Id to UserRole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to assign *UserRole* to *UserRoleId* - trying to assign sObject to Id.

Correct code would be:

```
user.UserRoleId=[select Id from UserRole where Name = 'CEO'].Id;
```